# Receive both file and complex type in ASPNET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post

I need to write an API call that takes as input both a file and a compound type involving a list of objects. The compound type looks like this:

```
    public class MyParameterInner {
        public string A { get; set;}
        public int B { get; set;}
    };

    public class MyParameter {
        public int X {get; set; }
        public MyParameterInner [] MyArray { get; set; }
    };
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public String Post(IFormFile file, [FromForm] MyParameter data) {
           return $"My array has {data.MyArray.Length} elements, my file has {file.Length} bytes";       
    }
```

Problem is I cannot figure out what to post to this controller for it to correctly parse `data.MyArray`. E.g., I tried the Swagger-generated curl:

```sh
> curl -ki -X POST "https://localhost:5001/My" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "X=4" -F 'MyArray={"A":"A","B":9}' -F "file=@Program.cs"

...
My array has 0 elements, my file has 715 bytes
```

What does the proper request for this controller look like? More generally, how do I write an ASPNET controller which accepts both a file and a compound type as inputs?

Comment: `form-data` requires plattened-keys to post a complex object, to post your `MyParameter`, you can try this `-F 'MyArray[0].A=A' -F 'MyArray[0].B=9'`

Comment: @KingKing  Thanks. You should elevate this to an answer so I can pick it.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad it helped, the answer is so simple that we can suggest as a comment, it's fine as in many other questions on SO.